# In this wind sensor, how can I increase the sampling rate (takes up to a minute to update)?

Tags: capacitor, sampling

I am using this [LaCross TX23U](https://www.lacrossetechnology.com/media/catalog/product/t/x/tx23u-it.pdf) wind sensor. Although not critical for this question, here is the [communication protocol](https://www.john.geek.nz/2012/08/la-crosse-tx23u-anemometer-communication-protocol/). The manual indicates a wind speed sampling rate of 4.5 seconds.

When the rotary is still, it reads out 0 mph, as it should. Turning the rotary will read a value, for example 5 mph.

Sampling it every five seconds, it takes a long time to reflect a change in rotation speed.

From standstill to a set speed it takes about 4 samples, or 20 seconds, to stabilize. Going from that set speed to zero, it keeps printing the same previous value for about 20 seconds, and then slowly reduces to zero over the next 40 seconds.

I suspect the rotation induces a current which charges a capacitor, accounting for the delay. Still, why would this result in a constant output for 20 seconds when I suddenly stop the rotary, instead of beginning to decrease immediately, even if slowly.

Also, is there anything I can do to improve the response time of the wind sensor? Up to 10 seconds would be acceptable for the project I need this for.

Comment: It's a commercial system. You can describe its behavior and all we can do is say, "Yup, that's what it does, I guess." If I didn't like what it did, I'd just go design my own and be done with it. If I were targeting COTS, I might design it to report info without averaging, given at the moment of sampling. But if sampled less frequently, then I might average the vector components and keep a maximum gust, too. I could then report average speed, direction, and maximum gust.

Comment: This might be interesting: "Sonic anemometers can be deployed to measure mean horizontal wind speeds with very high accuracy and at high frequency (Coquilla et al. 2010) (permitting detailed description of gusts.) The ability of 3-D sonic anemometers to accurately measure changes in wind direction and gusts, and their resistance to mechanical failures and icing, spurred the US National Weather Service to change all Automated Surface Observation Systems (ASOS) to ice-free sonic anemometers during the early 2000’s."

Comment: Are you using their wireless "thermo-hydro transmitter" to get the wind data?

Comment: @AliChen I'm using a Pi. Using info from linked protocol for this.

Comment: I think you need to open the thing up, check the way how it senses the rotation, and re-design the entire electronics.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you're not right about the assumption that this slowness is due to electronic properties of the motor.

On the contrary, I'd assume that the device does relatively low-cutoff filtering in the digital domain, for example simply by averaging several measurements. That way, you don't get a "noisy" jumping speed value, but something that is nicer to read.

On the flip side, you incur group delay, as you notice.

The fact that it rises faster than it falls is probably caused by the desire to be useful for assessing the weather: an average wind of 2 knots with bursts of 20 knots will certainly feel different than an average wind of 4 knots, even if the actual average is the same.

Comment: +1, I found this: "Due to the inertia of the rotating shaft, a cup or propeller anemometer also does not respond to a wind speed change immediately. This effect is quantified using a distance constant (\$\lambda_d\$) that is the distance the wind travels before the anemometer reaches 63.2% of a step change in wind speed, it is determined from wind 
tunnel tests  and is highly instrument specific. This constant
 is shorter when wind speed increases than when wind speed decreases, causing an overestimation in the measured mean wind speed (Brock and Richardson 2001; Papadopoulos et al. 2001.)"